# How to activate deactivated repository after upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to Raring from Quantal, and Bitdefender and Dropbox repositories are disabled.

Synaptic > other software > disabled on upgrade to raring

I try to put check in the box, but it is not marked.

What should I do to activate them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Synaptic Package Manager, go to Settings > Repositories.

[image]

Or go go to System Settings > Software & Updates, navigate to the Other Software tab.

There, you'll see one or more items labeled disabled. If you select one of these and click Edit, you'll see more details about the repository. To re-enable, just delete the comment, click OK, and check the check-box back in the main dialog. ( I don't have any disabled, but just follow the steps, and you'll be OK)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mitch but I already tried that before, but without success

Comment: I could not fix the problem so I did a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04